# Wrong character being stored to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serialization, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I created a dropdown for a view where the user can either select Y or N.

Answer (score 1):

```
ASCII 78 = 'N'
ASCII 89 = 'Y'
```

http://ascii.cl/

Your serialization code runs as expected.  Assuming you have debugged the controller code that is serializing the model to XML, it's possible another transformation is occurring when this XML is stored to the database.

Comment: So it's normal for the ascii value and not the actual character to show up when something is serialized to xml? My object has other properties that are strings, the only difference between them and the Y/N characters is that the other string values in my objects are greater than one character.

Comment: I tested your code and verified the IsFunded property was serialized as "Y" or "N" within the <IsFunded> tag.  Please provide the storage to database implementation.

Comment: I added some of the stored procedure code in my edit

Comment: The stored procedure code is a query, I don't see any calls to store the serialized XML.  Consider using XQuery instead of OPENXML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190262(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault for not adding the code in, but there is an INSERT statement right before the sql code that I put in my edit

Comment: It's storing a 7 for N and 8 for Y, and since my column is just varchar(1) I'm guessing it's storing the ascii value but just cutting off the second digit